# getElementById returns null reference

Tags: javascript

I have the following script in my page:

```
    window.onload = LoadElement;
    function LoadElement() {
        document.getElementsByTagName('asp:Panel');
    };
     function setPage(frame, page) {
         document.getElementById('WindowShow').innerHTML = page;
    }
```

At first I want the `asp:Panel` be read it onload. Continuing I'm calling the `setPage` Function in order to load a Page inside to this Panel...
But the debugger throws me the error `I can't load the porperty .innerHTML to a null reference value.
I see from the debugger that really the getElement has a value of null, but the value inside is not null.
Is someone to know what is going on here? I'm confused... very much...

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION'S**
The sub to use in order to call the script is this:

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        Dim url As String = "/Pages/Support/Asp/Help01.aspx"
        Dim urlURI As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
        Dim urlPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
        Dim root_url As String = Strings.Left(urlURI, urlURI.Length - urlPath.Length)
        Dim frameName As String = "WindowShow"
        iPageLoad(frameName, sender, root_url + url)
    End Sub
Public Sub iPageLoad(FrameId As String, sender As Object, msg As String)
        Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()
        Dim innerMess As String = msg
        Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
        Dim script As String = "setPage('" + FrameId + "', '" + innerMess + "')"
        If Not Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Me.GetType(), "iPage") Then
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "iPage", script, True)
        End If
    End Sub
```

**NEW SCRIPT**

```
<td  id="TD1" rowspan="9"  runat="server">
  <asp:Literal id="WindowShow" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setPage(page) {
            document.getElementById('WindowShow');
        }
    </script>

</td>
```

With this script throw me the error ìnnerHTML is not a valid attribute for...` .

**UPDATES**

That is what my code has:

```
    <table id="tbl" runat="server" class="maintable" >
    <tr><td id="line1" class="tableline" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" CssClass="tablebutton"  Text="bla bla bla" />
    </td>    
    <td  id="TD1" rowspan="9"  runat="server">
    <asp:Literal id="WindowShow" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setPage(page) {
            document.getElementById('WindowShow').innerHTML = page;
        }
    </script>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And that is what is Server site look like:

```
    <table id="MainContent_tbl" class="maintable">
    <tr>
       <td id="MainContent_line1" class="tableline">
       <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$button1" value="bla bla bla"      id="MainContent_button1" class="tablebutton" />
       </td>
      <td id="MainContent_TD1" rowspan="9">
    '--------- It Shaw the TD1 but can't see the Literal element
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setPage(page) {
            document.getElementById('WindowShow').innerHTML = page;
        }
    </script>

      </td>
    </tr>
</table
```

Comment: Show us `WindowShow` HTML part and how you call `setPage`

Comment: Where are you even calling `setPage`?

Comment: What do you expect "`LoadElement`" to do? Currently it does not really *do* anything.

Comment: @FelixKling I have set an additional updates in my question

Comment: You should look at the link at the bottom of my answer, on MSDN they have a VB example on that page. Just add Mode="PassThrough" and you'll be able to set the inner HTML on the server-side, which is quicker and easier.

Comment: That means I'll use the script... because until now your solution works but return me a text only... is not loading the new page on ti...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my issue which may close this question and probably opens another...

I use two scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = getTag()
    function getTag() {
        var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
        return td;
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myTD = getTag();
        function setPage(page) {
           // var ch = myTD.item(1).children[0];
            //ch.value = page;
            myTD.item(1).childNodes[1].innerHTML = '<iframe class="tablecolumndiv" src="' + page + '" />';  
        }
    </script>
```

And my asp.net code:

```
<td  id="TD1" rowspan="9"  runat="server" class="tablecolumn">
<div id="WindowShow" runat="server" class="tablecolumndiv">


</div>

</td>
```

In the first script I call `onload` for the `td` element.
In the second I call the returned `td` from the first and passes dynamically the page I want thru an `iFrame`. 
Now the question comes up is "Why I didn't do it from the asp.net code". 
Well I did that but I was facing the problem to leave the `iFrame` when I finish my job. 
So now... tomorrow... I'll try to close the dynamically opened `iFrame` and finish the all issue here...

Comment: You should put everything in the onload event. Because the second block is called after the first and the page might not be loaded (or the "td" element). Or put this JS code after the DOM creating. (in the body, if you used the <head>)

Comment: You can, anyway, cache the reference of TD which is loaded when the page is loaded and setPage will use it when the page is loaded or in the worst case return an error (prevent it w/ null check.) Something like: `var TDref; window.onload = function() { TDref = document.getElementsByName('td'); } function setPage(page) { if (TDref==null) return; TDref.etc = "..."; }` Anyway getElementsByTagName will return an array with doms.

Comment: Well... see... the `setPage` function is called from a `button_click` and these buttons are 9 in number, each button is for a deferent page to open... But even so I have the issue to close the `iFrame`... There a work to do... but the specific answer is closed...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `asp:Panel` use this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var panel;

    panel = document.getElementById('<%=ServerSidePanel.ClientID %>');

    // do something with panel
    setPage(panel, "<span>Page inside panel.</span>");
};

function setPage(frame, page)
{
     frame.innerHTML = page;
}
```

And in the code-behind expose the control in a property:

```
protected ServerSidePanel
{
    get
    {
        return ... // the panel you want to get in JS
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: server-side html injected panel

If you have the HTML on the server and want to have it inside the panel, there is no need to use JS at all. You can just assign it to a `Literal` instead of a `Panel` this way:

In the ASPX page:

```
<asp:Literal ID="injectionPoint" runat="server" CssClass="looks_like_a_panel" Mode="PassThrough" />
```

In the code behind (here in C#, sorry I don't speak VB):

```
string html;

// load somehow the html, here it is simply assigned
html = "<span>internal HTML</span>";

// assign html to literal
injectionPoint.Text = html;
```

That's all. No JS at all.

Here you can find a VB example doing pretty much the same, but without `PassThrough` mode:

[Literal VB example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4)

Comment: I have a Button to call the script... with variables

Comment: Please explain better in your question what you mean/need by "I have a Button"...

Comment: I set `<asp:Literal id="WindowShow" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough" />` and also I change my script... see on my up date... it doesn't understand the Literal as an element and not recognize the innerHTML as an attribute.